# Taking non-connecting flight from Dubai (DXB)

Tags: transit

I am currently studying in Canada since a year. I am planning to travel to Karachi, Pakistan in the mid of Dec 2015. Since connecting flights were quite expensive in that peak time, so I booked two non-connecting flight that first takes me from Calgary to Dubai, the other from Dubai to Karachi.

The confusion is I don't have visa for Dubai, so am I still able to use Dubai as transit route to take my another flight to Karachi and return back via same route?

Your response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks